# Show element by condition in GROUP

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, conditional-statements

Say, I have a table:

```
id ext_id param

1    5      0

2    5      1

3    6      0

4    6      0

5    7      1

6    7      1
```

respectively.

I wanna have a result like:

```
2 5 1

3 6 0

5 7 1
```

So that MySQL groups by ext_id and shows an element, that has maximum `param` value. If all are equal - I need any.

I tried something like:

```
SELECT * FROM t 
GROUP BY ext_id HAVING param = MAX(param)
```

but it did not do the trick ((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to find the maximum `param` for every ext_id, using a group by query. Then you have to join the result of this query again on t, where `ext_id` matches, and `param` is `max_param`:

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM (
  SELECT ext_id, max(param) as max_param
  FROM t
  GROUP BY ext_id ) t1 inner join t t2
  on t1.ext_id=t2.ext_id and t1.max_param=t2.param
GROUP BY t2.ext_id
```

Since there could be more than one row with the same maximum `param`, I'm grouping again by `ext_id`, MySql allows you to do so, so it will get just one row for each `ext_id`.